# Assert on the basis of queryTime from the sample response

Tags: jmeter

From the below response, want to fail the test if the `queryTime` value is more than `1000ms`.

Response Data:

```
{
  "metadata" :{
    "count" : 1,
    "pageSize" : 100,
    "page" : 1,
    "TotalPages" : 1,
    "queryTime" : "5224ms"
  },
  "result": {
     "transactionName" : "Test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSR223 assertion for this with some script inside,

```
var json = JSON.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
var queryTime = json.metadata.queryTime
var time = parseInt(queryTime.split("m")[0])
  
 if (time > 1000 )
{
log.info("QueryTime " + time);
AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

[image]